# To what extent is the Laughlin wave function the essence of the FQHE?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, quantum-hall-effect

The [Laughlin wave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laughlin_wavefunction) is not the exact ground state. Yet, it seems that it captures many key features of the [fractional quantum Hall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_quantum_Hall_effect).

So, the question is, to what extent is the Laughlin wave function relevant when it comes to the phenomena of the FQHE?

Is there any property for which the Laughlin wave function is completely irrelevant? Is there any phenomenon that is completely beyond the Laughlin wave function?

Answer (score 2):

The Laughlin wave-function is not the exact ground state of a lowest Landau level Coulomb interaction for filling factors $\nu=\frac{1}{m}$, but is very close and believed to be in the same universality class. The main difference is in the long distance correlation functions. The agreement can be improved significantly with a simple modification to the Laughlin wave-function http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.93.235149.

There are many phenomena that occur at other filling fractions which are not captured by the Laughlin wave-function. For example the pairing and non-Abelian excitations of the Pfaffian and Read-Rezayi wave-functions.